# (void) указатель на объект

Tags: c++

Разбираюсь в чужом коде и наткнулся на следующее:

```
CClientHandler* handler = new CClientHandler(sock, b);
(void)handler;
```

Что делает `(void)` перед указателем `handler`?

Answer (score 4):

Строки вида

```
(void)handler;
```

или

```
handler;
```

обычно используются, чтобы избавиться от предупреждений компилятора "Переменная ... не используется".
Если дальше по коду указатель используется, то эту строку можно удалить.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045615/what-does-voidvar-actually-do

Comment: Просто упоминание переменной (без приведения) приведет к другому предупреждению: `expression result unused`.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ узнать - закомментировать данную строку и выполнить компиляцию. Если далее по тексту функции нет упоминания `handler`, то исключение строки `(void)handler;` привело бы к появлению (при соответствующем уровне оповещения компилятора) предупреждения о неиспользуемой переменной (о чем уже сказано в ответе @goldstar_labs).

Однако, в упомянутой  ситуации можно было бы просто сократить код до следующего вида:

```
new CClientHandler(sock, b);
```

Comment: Вообще-то что-то наводит на мысль о возможной утечке памяти...

Comment: @Harry наводит. Но ровно этим же грешит и исходный код. Сделаем допущение, что внутри конструктора всё же как-то сохраняется `this` для последующего удаления.

Comment: А я о нем и говорю :)